# How to make HttpResponse print the new line?

Tags: django, httpresponse

```
def index(request):
    review = Review.objects.all()
    output = "\n".join([each_review.review_text for each_review in review])

    return HttpResponse(output)
```

The output which I get is

`"This book 1 is very great This book 2 is very great This book 3 is very great This book 4 is very great This book 5 is very great This something is very great"`

But it doesn't print the new line between them. How to make that happen just with `HttpResponse`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default `HttpResponse` has "text/html" as content-type, and html ignores newlines chars (or more exactly treats them as whitespaces).

If you want a text/html response content, you'll have to replace newlines by the appropriate html markup (either using `<br>` instead of newlines or wrapping each line in a `<div>` or `<p>` etc). You'll also need to wrap the whole thing into a proper html document, IOW adding the parent `<html>` and `<body>` tags around your content etc.

Else if a plain text content type is ok, just set the content-type header on your response:

```
return HttpResponse(output, content_type="text/plain")
```

so the browser knows to interpret and render it correctly.

As a side note: the way you're using both the orm and `str.join()` is vastly inefficient.

First, `str.join()` takes any iterable (as long as all the items are strings) so you don't need to build a `list` - you could just use a generator expression ie (notice the lack of brackets around the expression):

```
output = "\n".join(each_review.review_text for each_review in review)
```

But if you're only interested in a single field from the model, loading the whole fields and building a model instance is a complete waste of resources both at the database and python code levels. The solution here is to use a `QuerySet.value_list()` instead (here with the `flat` flag set to True since we only want a single field):

```
output = "\n".join(Review.objects.values_list("review_text", flat=True))
```

Answer (score 6):

you get a html so you should to use `<br>`

```
 output = "<br>".join([each_review.review_text for each_review in review])
```

or `<pre>`

```
 output = "\n".join([each_review.review_text for each_review in review])
 output = "<pre>{}</pre>".format(output)
```

Comment: Much better and simpler solution.